# Did I just brick my HTC One X

Tags: unbricking, htc-one-x

So today I unlocked bootloader on my HTC one X then flashed CWM recovery then attempted to install cyanogenmod. It said in the recovery that zip file installed successfully, but when I reboot it is stuck at the cyanogen logo boot screen. I did a full wipe before I installed the ROM. Now I cant use adb, device not detected, can't install another rom because I cant use the phone storage. All I can do now is go to the recovery or bootloader screens, the device is detected by my pc though. Did I just brick my phone? any leads to what I should do? I can lock/relock bootloader and flash the recovery

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic. Try this:

1. On your computer, browse your ROM .zip file, there should be a file named `boot.img` at top level. Extract it somewhere on your computer.
2. Plug your phone into your computer via USB cable.
3. Boot your phone into bootloader mode. (Power + Volume Down button for 5 seconds.) At bootloader screen your phone should say `FASTBOOT USB`.
4. Assuming you know where your `fastboot.exe` is on your computer, issue this command in `cmd`:

   `path/to/your/fastboot.exe flash boot path/to/your/boot.img`
5. After that restart your phone and see if it can boot into your ROM:

   `fastboot reboot`

Answer (score -1):

You Need 
WinDroid HTC One X Toolkit
HTC One X (At least 50% charge)
Windows XP - 8.1
USB Cable
Read this [XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2437459) this Can Help You..